# How to back up and restore all softwares and files from C drive when windows 7 boots but stops at black screen

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot

I have Windows7(32 bit) and Linux mint 16(64 bit)  dual boot computer. Windows 7 boots but stops at the black screen. But I can boot normally from mint and can access windows7 files through mint .
Now to repair I have done following process:

(i)Start up repair: It could not found any problem.

(ii)ctr+alt+delete or ctr+alt+esc also didn't show up task manager

(iii)Bootrec.exe using command prompt: and then all the things that people suggest to do. But unfortunately that destroyed grub menu. But I recovered that grub menu using "Try Ubuntu"
and then installing "boot repair". Now I can again access my computer using linux mint.

(iv)regedit using command prompt: I have done all things to change something to explorer.exe

(v) tapping shift buttons for more than five times. But that also didn't show up any thing.

None of the above method could solve the problem. I don't know whether there is any other methods to try. If any one suggests some other method I will try. If there is no other method to try, I want to back up all my installed software in C drive to mint or some external hard disk and then restore it after "custom" re-installation of windows7 . Don't bother about normal files in C drive as I can simply "cut and paste" those form windows 7 to linux mint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: firstly you have to repair the windows MBR then install mint grub after doing that both os is running fine.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than to backup all your apps, I would go with clean install. Just make a list of all applications you have installed, copy all data to some external drive, or to linux partition, format your windows partition and clean install fresh Windows and all your apps. I do that from time to time.

Comment: "Why don't you.." is this an answer?

Comment: @AthomSfere I wanted to write this as a comment, but at the time writing, my reputation didn't allow me to comment questions. I had less than 50 points. And that is only reason I put it as an answer. I am not expecting any votes on this answer, nor this comment. What about you, do you expect some votes on your comment? I have just provided some informations what would I do, an idea, maybe somebody will see it helpful. Unortunatelly it had to be in an answer format.

Comment: @AthomSfere Because of comments like yours, and nazi approach of some of the SU(and SO) moderators, there are a lot of people with huge knowledge in technology, that were active on these sites, but because of totally not needed negative experience they had here, now they are avoiding these sites. Just copy `Why stackoverflow sucks` and read some of the blogs on this subject. (Although I haven't had bad experience yet, and hope it will remain like that).

Comment: I Don't need / want upvotes and I think your answer is valid, but should be more authoritative and drop the "Why don't you". It does not directly address the question, but it does give a good work around that is more plausible to implement that trying to "backup" a bad Windows install.

Comment: @AthomSfere Well, if that simple `Why don't you` is the real problem here, moderator should remove that part as not needed, bad syntax, whatever. Its the freedom moderators have. May be that because english language is not my first language, and sometimes my answers may sound a little odd, but even then, the point and meaning of an answer is recognizable.

Comment: I wouldn't have guess english was not your primary language, as American English uses `why don't` often too, but for a Q&A specifically, where you are the authority of the post its bad form and changes the voice of the post dramatically. I was trying to subtly direct you to improving your answer and thus earn at least my upvote.

Comment: @AthomSfere Answer updated. I hope it sounds authoritative now ;)